# Regex to parse list items except blacklisted term

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to construct a single  regex that will match a list only if it contains a specific item in the list and return all other items in the list *except* the one that matched.

E.g.: With this list I want to match on *fruit* but only return *apple*, *orange* and *banana*:

```
apple, fruit, orange, banana
```

I'm currently trying variations of this:

```
\b(?:fruit)\b|[^,\s][^\,]*[^,\s]*
```

**This is a Java regex implementation but assume that I have no access to the code that's running the actual regex.**

Comment: use this regex [^,\s]+ because your fruit is in a no-capturing group (?:) = no-capturing group

Comment: @crammeur do you mean like this:
 \b(?:fruit)\b|[^,\s][^\,]*[^,\s]+  because that still doesn't work?

Comment: no just [^,\s]+ replace all regex by this

Comment: some of the list items are multi-words (they're actually content catagory names rather than this simple fruit example) so just [^,\s]+ doesn't work in this case

Comment: Ok i doesn't know that so try \b(fruit)\b|[^,\s][^\s]*[^,\s]* can work

Comment: New version \b[^,\s]*\s*(fruit)\b|[^,\s][^\s]*[^,\s]*

Answer (score 1):

Regex may not be the best tool here, but loading your items into a list may work better.  In the code snippet below, I convert your CSV list of items/fruits into a formal list.  With that list in hand, it is easy to determine if a certain item be present.  If `fruit` is found, then we can return the list minus that item, otherwise `null` is returned.

```
public List<String> getItems(String input, String match) {
    String[] array = input.split(",\\s*");
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
    if (list.contains(match)) {
        return list.remove(match);
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

String fruits = "apple, fruit, orange, banana";
List<String> result = getItems(fruits, "fruit");
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this case regex is the only option.

Comment: @BigMikeW Your question is a bit broad then.  A single regex can't do what you have in mind, you need more logic.  You should edit your question and make it clear what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, you should be able to simply match `(.*)\bfruit\b(?:, )?(.*)` and replace with `\1\2`

Answer (score 0):

[image]I have prepared the following regex that works fine for any position of your element in your list.

```
(.*)apple(,\s)(.*)|(.*)(,\s)apple(.*)
```

then you have to use the following backreference to construct your result list

```
$1$3$4$6
```

of course each time you use the regex you will have to change *"apple"* by the element that must be removed from the list, for this purpose create a variable that stores the element that must be removed and construct the regex dynamically by concatenating the following elements:

```
"(.*)" + elementToBeRemoved + "(,\s)(.*)|(.*)(,\s)" + elementToBeRemoved + "(.*)"
```

I have tried with **banana, apple, fruit and orange** and it works perfectly!!!